# on select event handler in jquery ui widget

Tags: jquery, user-interface, widget

i am having the following code in which on select of widget dropdown i have to get label to be selected , but it value been selected.... any work around plz..in firebug i am passing it correctly may be the select function call that makes some thing wrong.....

```
_autoSelect: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.label.selected = true;

            //Fires select event for entire widget
            this._trigger("select", e, {
                item: ui.item.label
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery when you have a checkbox/radiobutton :

```
    $('.yourClass').attr('checked')) {
        // your code to fire    
    }
```

on event handling you should build a function when your class is clicked to check if it is checked and then fire your code